# How to identify matching and unique rows across different columns in R data-frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am working on a large data-frame that has 4 columns and each column has variable rows. I am trying to find unique and identical pathways between the 4 columns (each column represents a particular day of treatment with a drug). Here below is a small example.

```
Pathways_1Day <- c("blood","kidney","testis","No","bone","liver","intestine","lungs","ABC","pancreas","Yes","spleen")

Pathways_2Day <- c("blood","kidney","testis","eyes","bone","cells","intestine","cervix","ABC","pancreas","None")

Pathways_3Day <- c("blood","kidney","vessels","lymph","t-cells","liver","intestine","lungs","ABC","epidermis","None")

df<-data.frame(Pathways_1Day,Pathways_2Day,Pathways_3Day)
```

I want to get a summary of the no of pathways that are common between different timepoints (1, 2 and 3 days).

**Important: The no of pathways is not the same for each day.**

I have tried this:

```
All_pathwayNames <- df%>%group_by_all%>%count
```

But the desired output is not what I am trying to get.

There can be different ways to address that. It will be great if I can get matching rows infront of each other across all columns.

Regards

Comment: Are pathways on different day with the same genes? Then It is just a matter to compare the names of each day via `setdiff(Pathways_3Day, Pathways_1Day)` for example. If not I would recommend it to work with lists instead of data.frame for this kind of data or use GeneSetCollection from GSEABase to read it and work with this.

Answer (score 1):

When I create the dataframe using the commands you have provided, I get an error, and the data frame can't be created:

```
Error in data.frame(Pathways_1Day, Pathways_2Day, Pathways_3Day) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 12, 11
```

What I *think* you were trying to do is something more like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
tibble() %>% 
  bind_rows(tibble(day=1, pathway = Pathways_1Day)) %>%
  bind_rows(tibble(day=2, pathway = Pathways_2Day)) %>%
  bind_rows(tibble(day=3, pathway = Pathways_3Day)) -> combined.tbl
```

Producing a long-format data structure that looks like this:

```
> combined.tbl
# A tibble: 34 x 2
     day pathway  
   <dbl> <chr>    
 1     1 blood    
 2     1 kidney   
 3     1 testis   
 4     1 No       
 5     1 bone     
 6     1 liver    
 7     1 intestine
 8     1 lungs    
 9     1 ABC      
10     1 pancreas 
# ... with 24 more rows
```

When laid out in this way, you can do something like grouping by pathway, and then do a `pivot_wider` to show the sets:

```
> combined.tbl %>% 
     group_by(pathway) %>%
     arrange(pathway) %>%
     pivot_wider(names_from=day, values_from=1)
# A tibble: 20 x 4
# Groups:   pathway [20]
   pathway     `1`   `2`   `3`
   <chr>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 ABC           1     2     3
 2 No            1    NA    NA
 3 None         NA     2     3
 4 Yes           1    NA    NA
 5 blood         1     2     3
 6 bone          1     2    NA
 7 cells        NA     2    NA
 8 cervix       NA     2    NA
 9 epidermis    NA    NA     3
10 eyes         NA     2    NA
11 intestine     1     2     3
12 kidney        1     2     3
13 liver         1    NA     3
14 lungs         1    NA     3
15 lymph        NA    NA     3
16 pancreas      1     2    NA
17 spleen        1    NA    NA
18 t-cells      NA    NA     3
19 testis        1     2    NA
20 vessels      NA    NA     3
```

And insert a filter to select only pathways that appear in all three days (i.e. `n() == 3`):

```
> combined.tbl %>% 
     group_by(pathway) %>%
     filter(n() == 3) %>%
     arrange(pathway) %>%
     pivot_wider(names_from=day, values_from=1)
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   pathway [4]
  pathway     `1`   `2`   `3`
  <chr>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 ABC           1     2     3
2 blood         1     2     3
3 intestine     1     2     3
4 kidney        1     2     3
```

Or at least two days (`n() >= 2`):

```
> combined.tbl %>% 
     group_by(pathway) %>%
     filter(n() >= 2) %>%
     arrange(pathway) %>%
     pivot_wider(names_from=day, values_from=1)
# A tibble: 10 x 4
# Groups:   pathway [10]
   pathway     `1`   `2`   `3`
   <chr>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 ABC           1     2     3
 2 None         NA     2     3
 3 blood         1     2     3
 4 bone          1     2    NA
 5 intestine     1     2     3
 6 kidney        1     2     3
 7 liver         1    NA     3
 8 lungs         1    NA     3
 9 pancreas      1     2    NA
10 testis        1     2    NA
```

Answer (score 0):

You're misusing data frames. Split the df into 4 vectors and use a Venn diagram generator to denerate a Venn diagram with the 4 vectors.

Adapting the first example from [here](https://r-graph-gallery.com/14-venn-diagramm)

```r
#untested
venn.diagram(
  x = list(df[,1], df[,2], df[,3], df[,4]), 
  category.names = colnames(df),
  filename = 'my_venn_diagram.png',
  output=TRUE
)
```

Comment: Good call @RamRS